# control initialize order when Python dataclass inheriting a class

Tags: python, inheritance, python-dataclasses

**What I kown**
The Python dataclass allows inheritance, either with dataclass or class.
In best practice (and also in other languages), when we do inheritance, the initialization should be called first. In Python it is:

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    ...
```

**What I'm doing**
Since the dataclass was introduced in Python 3.7, I am considering replace all of my classes with the dataclass. 
With dataclass, one of its benefits is to generate `__init__` for you. This is not good when the dataclass needs to inherit a base class -- for example:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

@dataclass
class Child(Base):
    a:int
    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

**My problem**
The problem is we have to put super initialization call inside `__post_init__` which in fact is called *after* dataclass's **init**.
The downside is that we lose the convention contract and the initialization disorder leads to that we can not override attributes of super classes.

It can be solved by concept of `__pre_init__`. I've read the document and does not see anything to do with that concept there. Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean with `we can not override attributes of super classes`? Do you want to have an attribute in the child class with the same name as in the parent class? Like, `class A: some_name: int` and `class B(A): some_name: int`?

Comment: @Arne Yes, attribute in the same name. In Scala or Java, parent always init first over child. and child attributes can always override parent after init.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. But I think that this kind of principle doesn't apply to the problem at hand. I used a few more words in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55097166/962190).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually there is one method which is called before `__init__`: it is `__new__`. So you can do such a trick: call `Base.__init__` in `Child.__new__`. I can't say is it a good solution, but if you're interested, here is a working example:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, a=1):
        self.a = a


@dataclass
class Child(Base):
    a: int

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        Base.__init__(obj, *args, **kwargs)
        return obj


c = Child(a=3)
print(c.a)  # 3, not 1, because Child.__init__ overrides a
```

Comment: One drawback to this though is that you must clutter client code with default value ```c = child(a=1)``` because ```c = child()``` gives error ```TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'```.  With this then, you're loosing the benefit of setting the default in ```def __init__(self, a=1)```.

Answer (score 12):

> In best practice [...], when we do inheritance, the initialization should be called first.

This is a reasonable best practice to follow, but in the particular case of dataclasses, it doesn't make any sense.

There are two reasons for calling a parent's constructor, 1) to instantiate arguments that are to be handled by the parent's constructor, and 2) to run any logic in the parent constructor that needs to happen before instantiation.

Dataclasses already handles the first one for us:

```
@dataclass
class A:
    var_1: str

@dataclass
class B(A):
    var_2: str

print(B(var_1='a', var_2='b'))  # prints: B(var_1='a', var_2='b')
# 'var_a' got handled without us needing to do anything
```

And the second one does not apply to dataclasses. Other classes might do all kinds of strange things in their constructor, but dataclasses do exactly one thing: They assign the input arguments to their attributes. If they need to do anything else (that can't by handled by a `__post_init__`), you might be writing a class that shouldn't be a dataclass.

Answer (score 5):

how about:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


class Base:
    def __init__(self, a=1):
        self.a = a


@dataclass
class Child(Base):

    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__init__()


ch = Child()
```

Comment: How is this different from what's in the question?

Comment: run the question code and run my code and you will see that my version does not require you to provide the argument when you instantiate child. apart from it there is no much difference.

Comment: I like this, but it prevents overriding attributes of super class...which is what @WeiChing is referring to in original question.  IOW, ```ch = Child(a=3)``` and ```ch = Child(3)``` both fail.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dataclass` inherit from `dataclass`:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Base:
    a: int = 1
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.b = self.a * 2

@dataclass
class Child(Base):
    def __post_init__(self):
        # super().__init__()  # this cause RecursionError
        super().__post_init__()  # without this, self.b is doesn't exist
        self.c = self.b * 5

ch = Child(a=3)
print(ch.a, ch.b, ch.c)  # Output: 3 6 30
```

Disclaimer: I'm still learning `dataclass` and can't find in the docs itself if this is recommended or not.